# Why does not I see error message when I use invalid database port?

Tags: java, jdbc, connection, database-connection, connection-string

I trying to get connection.

I have 3 different variants:

1:

```
 Connection connection = 
           DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/db1", "root", "");
```

---

2:

```
Connection connection =
        DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/db1",
        "root", "");
```

---

3.

```
Connection connection =
                    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:7777/db1",
                    "root", "");
```

Using each of these connections I can work with database properly.

But about using this parameter you can find mentions in almost every jdbc tutorial.

Expected result - get exception at least in third variant because this port obviously wrong.

Why do not I see error message?

Comment: In case of MySQL jdbc type 4 provider, when you doesn't provide port, it falls back to default port.

Answer (score 0):

`port` is not ignored (I've connected to a MySQL server running on a non-default port using this syntax).

The first two options are identical, since 3306 is the default port for MySQL. Not sure why the 3rd option works. Perhaps if you supply an invalid port, it falls back to the default port.

Comment: **Perhaps if you supply an invalid port, it falls back to the default port.** maybe... If you can find proove please let me know

Answer (score 0):

MySQL connection URL has the following format:

```
jdbc:mysql://[host][:port]/[database]
```

- `host` - The host name where MySQL server is running. 
          Default is 127.0.0.1 - the IP address of localhost.
- `port` - The port number where MySQL is listening for connection.
          Default is 3306.
- `Database` - The name of an existing database on MySQL server.
          If not specified, the connection starts no current database.

In the first case it works with default port 3306. Then it is same as the second case.

Comment: what about port 7777 in third row?

Comment: @gstackoverflow if it is a valid port connection will get through.

Comment: maybe I so lucker. lets imagine random port and I try to connect with your port and check result

Comment: *DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:1234/db1", "root", "");* 
leads to the same result

Comment: @gstackoverflow then if it  an invalid port it will set to the default port.

Comment: Can you provide quote from documentation about it?